# Recommended software VPN for Azure Private Cloud?

Tags: networking, cloud-service, vpn

I want to run several VPCs for several clients. I would like to stick to Azure as my company currently uses Microsoft as main vendor.

What I would like to accomplish is that client can use a software VPN solution to connect to their VPC. Our company strives to use multi-factor authentication, so ideally, the client uses the Azure Multi Factor authentication as backend for the software VPN.

Can you recommend any software VPN solutions that require very little of the end-users (preferably web-based, light on IT)?

Answer (score 1):

Would [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/overview.html) work? You could tie it into [Authy's](https://www.authy.com/integrations/openvpn) two factor authentication service. I would check this guide out, [azure-openvpn.github.io](http://azure-openvpn.github.io)